# Syntax: De-highlighting Certain Commands in TexShop

Tags: highlighting, syntax, texshop

There seem to be commands of various quality. A command like `\section` has some structural effects and differs considerably from commands like `\dots` or author-defined shortcuts (for example `\eg` for "for example") that rather affect the textual content than the documents layout and that are distracting when scattered all over the document. Nevertheless, both are highlighted very similar.

My question: Is there a(n easy) way to de-highlight pre-defined commands like `\dots` and author-defined commands like `\eg` in TexShop?

Comment: The highlighting of LaTeX commands is done by your editor. So, you should say which editor you are using. Most editors allow the user to change the highlighting scheme or even define new ones.

Comment: This depends entirely on the editor you use (which you didn't specify), and has very little to do with TeX. In some editors, such as `vim`, this would be very easy to do, yet I don't know if the same is true for TeXnixCenter etc. If you specify your editor we might be able to help you.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to customize the syntax highlighting patterns in TeXShop. :(

Comment: @AlanMunn Could you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to customize the syntax highlighting patterns in TeXShop.