# How to set the Texshop comment font to italics?

Tags: texshop

Does anyone know how to set a special font for comments in TexShop?
I would like to have it in italic with gray colour.
I used to use LaTex on Ubuntu and I just turned to Mac,
I'm therefore not familiar with TexShop fonts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: [This](http://thelivingpearl.com/2013/01/04/bringing-colors-to-texshop/) should be useful for changing the colour, but I'm not sure whether TeXShop allows for multiple font types in the input file.

Comment: It's not possible to select different fonts/fontshapes for syntax highlighting in TeXShop. You can only set colours.  See also [Syntax: De-highlighting Certain Commands in TexShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47597).

Comment: @AlanMunn Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to select different fonts/fontshapes for syntax highlighting in TeXShop. You can only set colours. See also [Syntax: De-highlighting Certain Commands in TexShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47597/2693).